# Questions about research help

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question about SCPC/NFC/NDEF. Basically I want to read and write NFC Tags with a cordless NFC reader on Linux **(not Android)**. I have read some documents about the specs of smartcards, their power supply and so on, but they were not really helpful.

I guess that any question about this topic would be closed or downvoted due to a lack of research, but I don't know how I can find this information. Please advise me on how I can ask that in a proper way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use <s>google</s> search engine(SE), your *mind* and experience. 
You have to break down the problem to it's parts.

You want a read NFC tags?

**great!**

1. Use you favorite SE and find something concerning only NFC tag
   writing.
2. Got stuck? Great! Post your code and the specific problem you
   encountered on Stack Overflow or a related site - SE offers https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ too

**Solved?**

**great!**

Now use your favorite SE to find a way to *write* nfc tags Repeat step 1,2.

Comment: As you may note by my count of reputation I'm no new user. My problem is that I googled a lot but I found no helpful informations. I found also documentation about smartcards which are together about 3000 pages. This was not helpful at all I'm looking for some kind of smuary or a kind of collection of relevent parts. About 99% was related on topic but not relevant for NFC. So far is your answer just my normal reseach. That means you would advice me to write a question, let's say on SO, that I simply setup up my hardware successful and I find now no docs how to continue?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=example+nfc+android&oq=read+nfc+android+&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l3j69i62l2.6706j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Okay good point! I missed to add that my target is not Android it's a linux box. I know that this is on the android site quiet simple :-)

Comment: @rekire that IS important :) try adding it to original question. Also if it's THAT hard to find give it a try. Worst case you'll get a few downvotes and get your question closed. Big deal. I guarantee an upvote from my self ;)